# JSF form with file upload and multiple select capabilities

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6, multiple-select

I am using JSF 2.0, and I have a form with a primefaces autoComplete (multiple) field, and a couple of file inputs. Since I'm using a file input, my h:form tag uses **enctype="multipart/form-data"** .

However, when I set my form to be multipart, my autocomplete field only returns the last item to my bean (the list is always of size 1). **This issue also occurs when just using a regular multiple select element** instead of the primefaces autocomplete (the autocomplete makes use of a hidden multiple select element). When I remove enctype="multipart/form-data", this issue goes away, but of course, my bean cannot detect the files I wish to upload.

Has anyone faced this issue and found a solution?

I am using: Liferay 6.1 GA2, Primefaces 3.5, Mojarra 2.1.21

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To anyone who is facing this issue, I would just like to share that I eventually turned to using jquery's autocomplete widget instead.

Answer (score 1):

Anghel Leonard describes in article [Uploading multiple files](http://www.packtpub.com/article/uploading-multiple-files) using pass through namespace (`http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough`) to add `multiple` attribute and overriding [FileRenderer#decode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.6/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/FileRenderer.java#FileRenderer.decode%28com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FacesContext,com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.UIComponent%29) method to extract uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with JBoss EAP 6.1. Turns out it's a bug in the implementation of the Request.java object which isn't fixed until Wildfly 8.x.  Reference here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/223085

To get around this, I used a filter from BalusC's blog: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html

Note that even though JBoss is a 3.0 servlet spec, I couldn't use BalusC's related blog entry for 3.0 because of the bug.